# Finding Inverse CDF of a Polynomially Distributed RV

Tags: polynomial

Let's say there exists
f(x) = 3(x-1)^2  0 < x < 1, 0 otherwise
Then the CDF would surely be
F(x) = 0 if x < 0, 3x^3 -9x^2 + 9x for 0 < x < 1 and 1 otherwise.

How would I go about finding the inverse CDF of this RV? I can't find any possible way to invert the CDF.

Comment: Your cdf is incorrect.  It should be $3 x - 3 x^2 + x^3$.  Then lookup "roots of cubic equation".

Comment: Oh that was honestly just a typo... I'm a bit confused as to how the roots will help me here though in terms of finding the inverse.

Comment: @guest122313 You see, the meaning of an inverse of CDF F^-1(p) is simply finding the x such that for that x, p=F(x). So the way of solving the equation is to solve the polynomial equation 0=F(x)-p, which is possible

Comment: Is there an easy method to solving a cubic where the constant is unknown? I've never encountered this problem before, and I'm not entirely sure where to start looking

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x) = 3(x-1)^2, x \in (0,1),\hspace{1mm} 0\hspace{1mm} \text{otherwise}$, then

$p = F(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}0 & x\leq 0 \\ (x-1)^3 + 1 & x \in (0,1) \\ 1 & x \geq 1\end{array}\right.$

Then you can invert by solving for $x$:

$x = F^{-1}(p) = \sqrt[3]{p-1}+1, p \in [0,1]$